# Why this D3 example does not work on my local machine?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The example link is http://bl.ocks.org/PatrickStotz/1f19b3e4cb848100ffd7, which is working fine. But when I copy file to my local machine and try to run localy it does not work.
I tried in Firefox and Chrome. It just shows the globe without circles. I also downloaded json file and make it look like and convert it to that geojson. I quite certanly think that they are the same. It shows data in console when I console.lot it. But it won't show circles nor rotate the globe. It doesn't show any errors in console. I also tried with python simple server.

Comment: the example link works fine for me. maybe check the console, if all resources could be loaded.

Comment: did you use local server? how did you get the data?

Comment: I am asking if this works on your local computer, the page itself is working.

Comment: Did you know bl.ocks.org uses gists? Here's the source https://gist.github.com/PatrickStotz/1f19b3e4cb848100ffd7

Comment: @Prinzhorn I did not know. Tnx a lot!